# Implementing custom authentication (MVC5)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im really new to anything referred to coding. Atm I created an MVC project (no authentication method) based on [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorial. Now it looks like a project where I can add new Employees and information about them (including UserName, Password, date of birth, name, adress, phone number, etc ). How can I add an login page that will use Username and Password from this form? Also, I wanna add some kind of roles, that only Administrator can add new Employees, and give them a role ( Employee/Admin ). I have seen tons of tutorials but it seems kinda too sophisticated for me.

Comment: I would argue this is off topic for stack overflow. You need to spend some time properly learning how to use both the language and framework. Keep doing research and do your best to follow any tutorials you find. If you have a _specific programming related problem_ during your learning then come back here and ask about it and we can do our best to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is to create another project and and look how it's done there:

[image]

Otherwise this would get quite long in any detailed explanation.

If you want a detailed explanation about how the UserManager is working and how to extend your `ApplicationUser`, have a look here for a free video course: http://pluralsight.com/training/Player?author=scott-allen&name=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals-m3-identity&mode=live&clip=0&course=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals

If you want a good resource collection about the topic, have a look here:
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources

Comment: Hey , thanks, but thats the point, my task is to not use the "Individual User Accounts" , I must create a custom authentication login page that uses my database data (Username and Password). Thanks for the links, ill check them out right now.

Comment: @SergiuSău that's exactly why I wrote that. There is no easy way out, so you should learn your trades and get into the topic on your own. It's all right there, but you have to understand it.