# How can I implement custom authentication/authorization in asp.net MVC without Identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a asp.net MVC 5-solution where I now need to implement authentication and authorization. The solution has a external service managing the "Heavy work" that will take the username and password on every request, and on successfull verification send back a token with the users permissions(roles) which should be matched against Attributes in the controller.

A request to the external service should be made on every request to my solution. How can I implement this in a simple way in my exising asp.net MVC 5-solution? I have looked at Identity and Owin but they feel overly bloated for what Im trying to achieve. I've also found some info about Forms auth, but it seems to be deprecated?

The workflow I have tried with is something like this:

A user request a controller. The controller is marked with an attribute like "Require(Roles="IT")". I implement the IauthenticationFilter and call my service in the OnAuthentication to verify the users request. From the return I will verify that the user is in fact who he says he is and also if he is permitted to enter the said action on said controller.

Any input is appreciated as I'm having a hard time finding solid info on how to implement a custom auth-solution. Is there any best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [IdentityServer4](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/)?

Comment: Basically we have a full identity-solution rolling as a service which will do the heavy lifting and administration. But now we have a small mvc-solution which needs to use this. So what Im looking for is more of a way to tell MVC to for each request ask our identity server for credentials instead of built in identity.

Comment: I guess as you already said, is a matter of implementing a custom. About Best practices, that's mostly a opinion based question, so you will get a lot of them, or none.. [Customizing ASP.NET Authentication with Identity](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/customizing-asp-net-authentication-with-identity-8647), [Implementing custom authentication (MVC5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612257/implementing-custom-authentication-mvc5), usually I go with IdentityServer, sorry, can't help much :(

Answer (score 2):

MVC builds upon ASP.NET's interfaces `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity`. If you implement these interfaces, you can tap into the existing `[Authorize]` / `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute functionality of MVC and only extend it if you need some functionality other than users/roles.

I won't repeat the implementation here - there are several posts about how to properly implement these interfaces (which should be set in the `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` event in ASP.NET/MVC).

- [ASP.NET MVC - Set custom IIdentity or IPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1064271/181087)
- [ASP.NET MVC - Custom IIdentity or IPrincipal with Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43983374/181087)
- [Implementing IPrincipal and IIdentity in MVC with use of custom membership and role provider](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6597243/181087)
- [using custom IPrincipal and IIdentity in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10742259/181087)
- [IdentityReboot - open source example of custom security provider](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.IdentityReboot)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. I will look through it!